# remove zero from infinite float list

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, quickcheck

I want to sample from an infinite list of floats for **QuickCheck** consumption. However, as I intend to use division, I want to remove **zero** from that list. It is such a conceptually simple problem I was wondering if I could do it with a list comprehension, and if not, which would be the simplest way to achieve this in Haskell?

```
[x | x <- floats, x /= 0] -- this seems reasonable, but where do I get floats from?
```

My current workaround (yuck):

```
import Test.QuickTest

divGen :: Gen (Maybe Float)
divGen = do
    x <- arbitrary
    if x /= 0
    then return $ Just x
    else return Nothing
```

Comment: "Where do I get `floats` from?" is quite a question; I don't see that it can be answered from the information given. What do you want to be in that list...?

Comment: @DanielWagner, check my edit. That workaround works and gives me the  kind of values I expect.

Comment: It seems your actual question is how to generate an infinite list of random floats? The list comprehension in the question is perfectly fine for filtering zero elements out of an infinite list of floats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate `arbitrary` values that satisfy a given predicate using the [`suchThat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:suchThat) combinator of QuickCheck:

```
divisor :: Gen Float
divisor = arbitrary `suchThat` (/= 0)
```

Example usage:

```
my_prop x = forAll divisor $ \d -> (x / d) * d =~= x
```

Comment: It is a hard choice between yours and @Zeta's answer. Both improved my knowledge of QuickCheck. Thanks!

Comment: Where does the `=~=` operator come from?

Comment: `=~=` here is meant to be a sufficiently inexact comparator (since comparing `Double`s exactly isn't a good idea). See e.g. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/elynx-tools-0.5.0/docs/ELynx-Tools.html#v:-61--126--61-

Answer (score 5):

That's already in QuickCheck, namely [`NonZero`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Modifiers.html#v:NonZero). Your infinite list of floats can be modeled as

```
nonZeroFloat :: Gen Float
nonZeroFloat = fmap getNonZero arbitrary

-- You probably want to use a shorter name:
infiniteListOfNonZeroFloats :: Gen [Float]
infiniteListOfNonZeroFloats = infiniteListOf nonZeroFloat
```

Afterwards, you can use `forAll`:

```
prop_something = forAll infiniteListOfNonZeroFloats $ \xs -> ...
-- or
prop_something = forAll (infinitelistOf $ getNonZero `fmap` arbitrary) $ \xs ->
                    ...
```

Note that the use of `NonZero` is a lot smoother with pattern matching:

```
prop_nonzero :: NonZero Float -> ...
prop_nonzero (NonZero x) = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you intend only to remove zeros from a list then you can do the following:

1. Function definition:

   ```
   withoutZeros:: (Eq a,Num a)->[a]->[a]
   ```
2. This code will drop all the zeros. You can drop any number just by changing the condtion inside the (/=).

   ```
   withoutZeros =filter (/=0)
   ```

I used  `(Eq a,Num a)` in my function definition because `Eq a->` is required for the comparison (i.e. `(/=)`) and `Num a->`. This will let you use this function on both Integer and Float lists.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Did you know you can use markdown-style formatting in your answers and preview them before you post? I've submitted an edit to your answer to make it more readable, but I'm not very familiar with Haskell, so feel free to fix any errors I may have accidentally introduced.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I do it with a list comprehension?

Sure, that comprehension looks fine to me.

> Where do I get `floats` from?

Depends what you want to be in it.

For your generator code, the only comment I would make is that rejection sampling is the usual trick:

```
divGen = do
    x <- arbitrary
    if x /= 0 then return x else divGen
```

Comment: Does that work for you? I tried it before, and `sample divGen` gave me an infinite loop.

Comment: Does `arbitrary` loop infinitely or always return 0?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, I ran it in `Interactive-Haskell` (Emacs) and it just hanged until I interrupted it. No value was returned.

Comment: You want `arbitrary \`suchThat\` (/= 0)`